# my function cant get called in JavaFx

Tags: java, listview, user-interface, javafx, scenebuilder

I have created a list view in FXML with the id of "lwAllUserGrp" I can use that id and the following function to populate it :

```
public void populateAllUserList() {
        lwAllUserGrp.getItems().clear();
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////
        String filter = txtSearch.getText();
        String Query = "Select user_name, user_login_name, user_state from dm_user where r_is_group = 0 and user_state = 0  and (user_name not like 'dm%' and user_name not like 'svc%' and user_name not like 'lexo%' ) order by user_name";
        ArrayList<String> AllUser = GetDataWithDql(_session, Query, "user_name");
        for (String x : AllUser) {
            if (x.toLowerCase().contains(filter.toLowerCase())){

                lwAllUserGrp.getItems().add(x);

            }

        }
    }
```

But when I add the following function to see which row is selected :

```
public void selectedItemFromListView(){
         //      System.out.println("blabla");
         selected = lwAllUserGrp.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
//       System.out.println(selected);
         String Query = "select user_name , user_state , user_address, user_login_name , user_web_page from dm_user where user_name ='@aclname'";
         Query = Query.replace("@aclname",selected );
         ArrayList<User> allUserNames = GetDataWithDqlpro(_session, Query, "user_name","user_address","user_state","user_login_name","user_web_page");
         for (int i = 0 ; i < allUserNames.size() ; i++ ){
             if (selected.compareToIgnoreCase(allUserNames.get(i).getUsername() ) == 0){

                    username.setText(selected);
                    login_Name.setText(allUserNames.get(i).getuserLoginName());
                    state.setText(allUserNames.get(i).getState());
                    address.setText(allUserNames.get(i).getAddress());
                    WP.setText(allUserNames.get(i).getuserWP());
             }

         }


}
```

my function doesnt get called at all ? any one knows the reason why ?

Comment: Did you use that `System.out.println` to verify that the function is not getting called? If not, is it possible that  `allUserNames` is empty / the comparison in that loop never succeeded and so it only *appeared* that it wasn't being called? Also, the obvious question: How are you calling that function? It won't call itself; you have to either call it from somewhere or e.g. register a listener.

Comment: @JasonC   to make sure the function is getting called or not I added System.out.println("blabla"); at the very begining of the function but no out put was found :(

Comment: Show the code where you are actually calling the function.

Comment: @JasonC  such a good question I had forgotten to add "onMouseClicked="#selectedItemFromListView" in my FXML :D

Comment: Do you have any other listeners in use? I tested it and onMouseClicked gets called. What suprised me is that onMouseReleased didn't get called when i had onMouseClicked in use.

Comment: @Clayn I have only used the "onMouseClicked" for my list view and for other buttons that I have I have used onAction="functionName" and they all work fine :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you aren't calling the function, it isnt going to call itself :) You'd have to add it as a listener or whatever. In your case,, you were missing the listener assignment in your FXML (I had a hunch that's why i asked). As you discovered in comments, adding the appropriate `onMouseClicked` specifier in your FXML should take care of it.